# Item-level Permission in a SharePoint 2013 BCS External List

Tags: sharepoint-2013, bcs

Can we have Item-level Permission in a BCS External List?

(I tried Advanced Settings to set Item-level Permissions, But cannot find the same, Used User Impersonation in BCS Connection Properties but throwing error)

Answer (score 0):

We can not set item level permission in ECT

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no built in functionality I found this useful while creating External List with BDC Service, and was able to filter by current user.

[External Lists (BCS): Read List User Context filter](http://www.thesharepointbar.com/?p=340)

Comment: the link seems dead. what idea did you find useful there?

Comment: I hope that link is temporarily down, it was like this "Export the BDC Metadata Model from SharePoint Designer and edit it by hand to include the UserContext filter. Then reimport the model through the BDC Service Application in Central Administration."